# Filter braches in Version Control log for HEAD and the upstream of HEAD in Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea, branch

I am using Intellij with git and want to filter the shown commits in the log tab.

I want to see only those commits that are on

1. my current branch,
2. on the remove of my current branch and
3. on the develop branch

1 and 3 are easy to achieve, but I did not manage to complete 3.
I can filter the branches by clicking on branch and then select.

What can I enter to achieve 3 and to avoid to explicitly add the branch `origin/feature/xxx`? 
I read that `@{u}` references the upstream but doesn't work here.

[image]

Thanks,
Zian

Comment: Have you checkout out the `develop` branch?

Comment: No, i haven't.  I want to see if and how my HEAD diverges from its origin (f.e. via rebase).

Comment: I think you need to edit your question a bit to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way to achieve what you need. There is a generic filter called HEAD, but it watches for the HEAD ref and does not know what branch it tracks. The `@{u}` reference is internal git shortcut and appears to be not recognized by IDE.

Note that the branch filter accepts regexp, so as kind of a workaround you could build some regexp to include all branches you need and to use it as the filter. It will not follow branch switch though.

BTW, in 2018.2 EAP the Branches filter has been updated, and now allows filtering by favorites branches. Appears it could help to achieve what you want.